# How to create a drop down menu like youtube has?

Tags: css, html, youtube

If you go to http://www.youtube.com/ right now there is a drop down button you press next to the youtube logo and it brings up a menu that has content in it, it brings it up on on the left side of the page and it doesn't go away when you scroll. how would you create this menu ?

Comment: it's just a column with ability to show or hide by clicking on the menu dropdown button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use a combination of Css, jQuery, etc. To give you a quick idea on how to accomplish this, it looks like a top div, left div(fixed) and a right div where the content is.

CSS example:

```
#ScrollContent {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    outline: 1px solid;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background: #C0C0C0;
    clear: left;
}


#Menu {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;

    position: fixed;
    outline: 1px solid;
    background: #92c452;
}
```

jQuery Example:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#hideshow').live('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#Menu').toggle('show');
    });
});
```

I have created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQQ6s/31/) To give the basic idea.. it is by NO MEANS the perfect fiddle, but I hope it helps you accomplish what you want.

Good luck,

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're after might be jPM: http://jpanelmenu.com/

Completely customisable. I have used this for a few businesses such as:

http://www.kapowinteractive.com.au/

If you bring the width in, you can see an icon pop up in the top left corner. Click it and the navigation opens up. I think this may be a good starting point for you.